# SQL Query to Compare Differences between Tables Rows between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to compare two database table records and return the results into separate table.

For example, I have a total of 6 columns in each table A B C D E F. However, I'm only comparing on the records in columns A, B, & C

If there is a match in in each table of columns A B C I would like the results to be outputted to new table (.csv file etc) for the row that matched

Let me illustrate:

In Table A you can see 6 columns, A B C D E F. The table has the following rows:

[image: Table A]

Table A

Table B also has 6 columns A B C D E F

[image: Table B]

From the tables you can see that only one row has match on A B & C i.e xx, PP, dd.

I would like that row to be outputted to a table with all the records in that row ie. xx PP dd TYH ADF AD

Comment: Do your tables have `UNIQUE` constraints on (A, B, C), or there can be multiple rows with the same combination?

Comment: Please add your expected output data for the given input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far from being complicated this is SQL bread and butter... you are looking for a join condition e.g.

```
select A.*, B.*
from TableA A
inner join TableB B on A.A = B.A and A.B = B.B and A.C = B.C
```

where A.* is all the columns from table A (TableA) and B.* is all the columns from table B (TableB)

Edit: Based on your clarified requirement for a separate row from tables A & B, try the following:

```
select convert(bit,1) Is_Deleted, A.A, A.B, A.C, A.D, A.E, A.F
from TableA A
inner join TableB B on B.A = A.A and B.B = A.B and B.C = A.C
union all
select convert(bit,1) Is_Deleted, B.A, B.B, B.C, B.D, B.E, B.F
from TableB B
inner join TableA A on A.A = B.A and A.B = B.B and A.C = B.C
order by A, B, C
```

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, I forgot to mention that I would like the output from both table 1 and table 2.

Comment: @Dale, I thought I need to do a UNION, or DISTINCT .. but then again I'm a newbie

Comment: @DaleBurrell, your query is closer to what I need. However, I would need second results on the row immediately below. At the moment the second results in on the same row but with columns A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1. I would like the second results on row immediately below.

Comment: Also, can you let me know what select A.*,B.* does?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, Im smiling from ear-to-ear. Thanks so much. I just need one other thing added to each row, but I'm just thinking how to phrase the question.

Comment: So, we now have two rows from the query. The row from TableA is the result from original table (TableA)  and the row from TableB is the new table (TableB). I would like an additional column, lets call it Is_Deleted to have the number 1 added to it from the original table (TableA). .. don't know if you'll be able to understand that.. I'm finding very hard to explain

Comment: at the moment we columns A B C D E F with the results in each row. However I would like columns to look like: Is_Deleted A B C D E F with the first row looking like 1 xx PP dd TYH ADF AD and the second just looking  xx PP dd TYH ADF AD

Comment: oh I think I see what you mean by Union. So what I therefore need is for the results to be outputted to another database/file/table. So to explain I need the results sent to another table/file with same number of columns but with one extra column called 'Is_Deleted' or any name. Under the 'Is_Deleted' column I need the record/row from TableA.... I really wish I could draw it out. Are you happy to move the discussion to chat?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, can you let me know what you mean by 'ust put 0 is the second row as I've shown... and I'm sure you can move the column from the being the last to the being the first'

Comment: @DaleBurrell are you able to help modify your script such that we don't only compare on columns A B C, but the records in col B need to match before the results are returned?

Comment: @Carltonp Sorry I'm not following, please update your question such that the sample data and expected results explain exactly what you require.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear if you want the output from table 1 or table 2. Though the query will be quite simple.

```
SELECT t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D, t.E, t.F
FROM  TableA t
INNER JOIN TableB tt ON (t.A = tt.A AND t.B = tt.B AND t.C = tt.C)
```